# Cannot connect to fedora via ssh (iptables)

Tags: ssh, iptables, fedora

I recently ssh-ed into my fedora machine at work.  I ran the command:

```
systemctl start iptables.service
```

Now I can't ssh back into the machine.  So far ssh has been my only way to access the machine.

Is there anything I can do to get around this? (I don't have physical access to the console)

Comment: Log in at the console and fix the firewall.

Comment: I don't currently have physical access to the console.  Is there a way to do this remotely?

Comment: There would be, if you hadn't firewalled yourself out!

Comment: `Is there a way to do this remotely?` - Contact someone that does have physical access to the console.  Have them fix it.

Comment: Actual footage of this incident: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYHci_KYIT4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides logging in at the console, as Michael recommended, the only other thing you could do is power-cycle the machine (and this would only work if iptables wasn't set to start up automatically).  Otherwise you're probably stuck.